# Create a new, named column based on a formatted numeric variable

Tags: sas

I have a dataset (DIN) that consists of formatted numeric variables (e.g., column 1 'BLD' has values 1-3, but they are formatted as 'Yes', 'No', 'Unknown'). All columns have slightly different formatting.

In each row, only one column has a value, the rest are missing. I am trying to use the following to get the maximum of each row (which will always be the non-missing value)

```
data DIN;
    set DIN;
    MAX = max(of BLD--VASC);
run;
```

Unfortunately as these columns are numeric the `MAX` column is showing as numbers, not the formatted value. I have tried using `vvalue` to get the formatted value, like below but I don't know how to do this for all columns at once.

```
data _null_;
    set DIN;
    BLD_C = vvalue(BLD);
run;
```

I felt like a `do` loop might help, and I tried looping over an array of variable names, but it just doesn't work. Nothing seems to happen

```
data DIN_C;
    set DIN;
    array nums(*) _numeric_;

    do i = 1 to dim(nums);
        nums_C = vvalue(nums(i));
    end;
run;
```

Can anyone help me? Or is there another approach I could take for this problem?

Comment: This problem is not clearly explained. If your variables have different formats, they surely have different meanings and I don't see the use of maximising. Further, what will you do if two variables have the maximal value, but their formatting is different?

Comment: That whole approach seems flawed. Don't try to do it mathematically; write (or write a macro to write) a SELECT statement like 'if BLD ne . then MAX = vvalue(BLD); if VASC ne . then MAX = vvalue(VASC);' etc. You might also find this gets much easier if you transpose the data to a tall-narrow format - the tyoe of problem you face here is exactly why wide data structures are bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MAX() to find the actual non-missing numeric value. Then use WHICH() to find the index number of the variable with that value. Now you can use VVALUE() to find the formatted value of that variable.

```
data DIN_FIXED;
  set DIN;
  array _num BLD--VASC
  length max 8 max_formatted $50 ;
  MAX = max(of _num[*]);
  if not missing(max) then max_formatted=vvalue(_num[which(max,of _num[*])]);
run;
```